# What is the word for "history of the study of the subject"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, american-english, terminology

Suppose the subject is nutrition. Is there a word for *the history of the study of nutrition*?  Or *the history of the study of a science* for that matter? I thought it was one of those *epi*-ology words like epistemology but I was way off.

You know how if you go to a Wikipedia page on any of the natural or social sciences, they'll have a "History" section. Is there a better word for that?

Comment: Maybe because it's not such an important concept, it doesn't have a name.

Comment: One difficulty is that *history of the study of X* is not the same as *the study of the history of X* and the latter is more likely to have a name.

Comment: It is normally called the *history of science/philosophy/etc.* in university courses. As Barrie says below, *historiography* has its own word. But not many other names of sciences allow *-graphy* to be attached. You could say *meta-science*, which would be the "science of science", as in studying the practice of science in a scientific way, but that one's iffy, let alone with other words.

Comment: I guess I'll just go with *history of `science`* for now.

Answer (score 2):

The study of history writing is *historiography*, so you want to might try and work on that.

Comment: The historiography of nutrition history?